# Someone who is always there for you

Tags: single-word-requests

can anyone help with this please? Is there a single word that can be used to refer to someone who is always there for you, like a father or a mother who does every little thing for you? Like s/he is like sticking up for you, embracing and covering you up by doing everything for you? Thanks.

Comment: Please explain the situation. There're various scenarios in life. Who's the "you" here?

Comment: Your rock. Your stalwart.

Answer (score 2):

We often refer to someone who is always there supporting you as:

> - a *rock*.

Here's an entry from Collins:

> **rock** (rɒk)
>
> n
>
> 4. a person or thing suggesting a rock, esp in being dependable, unchanging, or providing firm foundation.

**Ref**: Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003

Answer (score 0):

There are several words and phrases, from **guardian-angel** to **a real friend**.

- guardian-angel
- a real friend
- a protector
- a patron saint

> - guardian-angel - "a person who looks after or is concerned with the welfare of another."
>     [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/guardian+angel)
> - patron saint - "a saint who is believed to protect a particular place, activity, or group of people."
>     [MD](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/british/patron-saint)
> - protector - "a person or thing that protects someone or something" [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/protector)

e.g.

"I would like to thank all those who helped me, especially John who has been like a guardian-angel, with encouraging words when the odds were against me."

"Prince Charles is the new patron saint of unfashionable causes." [The Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/prince-charles/11610563/Prince-Charles-is-the-new-patron-saint-of-unfashionable-causes.html)

Comment: Other possibilities: *champion, advocate, mentor,* depending on the specifics of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

That person could be considered **nurturing**.

> [nurturing](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nurturing?s=t) (verb): to feed and protect; **to support and encourage, as during the period of training or development**

Although if they do it too much, they could end up **smothering** you.

> [smother](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/smother?s=t) (verb): to surround (with) or envelop (in): *he smothered her with love*